# How to average first instance of a value across the other instances of the value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like such:

```
ID          Instance         Value
-------------------------------------
52349          1              10
13523          1              15 
13523          2              20
13523          3              30
12356          1              10
12356          2              15
22355          1              23
```

I need to have the value of the first instance of an ID average out to the first, second, and third instance, and the value of the second instance of an ID to average out to the second and third instance. The final result I am looking for looks like:

```
ID          Instance         Value
-------------------------------------
52349          1              10
13523          1               5 
13523          2              15
13523          3              45
12356          1               5
12356          2              20
22355          1              23
```

If you look at ID number 13523 this is how the value should be broken down:

15    **5**
20    **5   10**
**30    5   10**

Adding the bolded values gives the values I am looking for

Comment: This is a bit confusing, can you restate with more math to explain your output?

Comment: Sure, take a look at ID 13523. There are three instances associated with it: 1, 2, 3. Each instance has its own value. Since there are 3 instances, I want to take the value of the first instance (15) and divide it by 3, so that it's averaged across instance 2 and 3. So now each instance has a value of 5. Now taking the value of the second instance (20), I want to average that across instance 3. So now instance 1 has value of 5, and instance 2 has value of 5+10. Instance 3 doesn't have another instance to average so its (30+5+10)

Comment: Ah... now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
df['newValue'] = df.groupby('ID')['Value']\
                   .transform(lambda x: (x / (x.notnull().cumsum()[::-1].values)).cumsum())
```

Output:

```
      ID  Instance  Value  newValue
0  52349         1     10        10
1  13523         1     15         5
2  13523         2     20        15
3  13523         3     30        45
4  12356         1     10         5
5  12356         2     15        20
6  22355         1     23        23
```

#### Details:

Within each group of ID with `groupby`, use `transform` to create a new value.

Transform the value, x, by first using `notnull` and `cumsum` to create a running count of values, then use `[::-1]`, a reversing element, to count backwards, divide X by that backwards count and use `cumsum` to calculate the running total of the averages.

Comment: I have, since I'm a new user, the score is recorded but not shown, thank you again